# SSH use_groups with PAM and chroot

Tags: ssh, pam, chroot

How to solve the problem:

> /etc/security/chroot.conf 17: found @group style syntax, but use_groups has not been turned on

I've work a little bit with `PAM` and `chroot` on `SSH` and have locked out from my system. After booting the recovery system, the `auth.log` says, that `use_groups` is not turned on.

```
Aug  1 07:09:09 ***** systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug  1 07:09:09 ***** pam_chroot[1085]: session: reading config file (/etc/security/chroot.conf)
Aug  1 07:09:09 ***** pam_chroot[1085]: session: /etc/security/chroot.conf 17: found @group style syntax, but use_groups has not been turned on
Aug  1 07:09:09 ***** pam_chroot[1085]: session: error determining chrootdir: user="root", dir="(null)"
Aug  1 07:09:09 ***** pam_chroot[1085]: session: returning failure
```

Aug  1 07:09:09 friendlounge pam_chroot[1085]: session: error determining chrootdir: user="root", dir="(null)"
Aug  1 07:09:09 friendlounge pam_chroot[1085]: session: returning failure

I've tried to set `AllowGroups` on the `sshd_config`, but the problem not solved. How i can enable `use_groups`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer is very hidden.

On the GitHub-Repository i've found the [options](https://github.com/gpjt/pam-chroot/blob/0709cbb426243527ebb93deb8939ebb1deb6884c/options).
The problem is, there has no samples for that.

If you wan't to add these options, you must change your **/etc/pam.d/ssh** file where you placed the `session    required     pam_chroot.so`.

Add at the end the given options. For sample, enable debug and allow groups:

> session    required     pam_chroot.so debug use_groups